# SSIS Student, ETL Staging Process

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, ssis, etl

I'm trying to perform a ETL Staging Process but keep running into this error. Turning off UAC as Microsoft suggests, setting XACT ABORT ON and all other things, nothing helps. 
This is the error I get when I start debugging it on Visual Studio. Would really appreciate some assistance.

```
SSIS package "D:\Demofiles\Lab01\Starter\AdventureWorksETL\Stage Data.dtsx" starting.
Executing ExecutePackageTask: D:\Demofiles\Lab01\Starter\AdventureWorksETL\Extract Internet Sales Data.dtsx
Information: 0x4004300A at Extract Customers, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
Information: 0x4004300A at Extract Internet Sales, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
Information: 0x4004300A at Extract Customers, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
Information: 0x4004300A at Extract Internet Sales, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
Information: 0x4001100A at Extract Internet Sales Data: Starting distributed transaction for this container.
Information: 0x4004300A at Extract Customers, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
Information: 0x40043006 at Extract Customers, SSIS.Pipeline: Prepare for Execute phase is beginning.
Information: 0x40043007 at Extract Customers, SSIS.Pipeline: Pre-Execute phase is beginning.
Error: 0xC0202009 at Extract Customers, Customers [2]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E37.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E37  Description: "Invalid object name 'cdc.lsn_time_mapping'.".
Error: 0xC004701A at Extract Customers, SSIS.Pipeline: Customers failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0x80040E37.
Information: 0x4004300B at Extract Customers, SSIS.Pipeline: "Staging DB" wrote 0 rows.
Information: 0x40043009 at Extract Customers, SSIS.Pipeline: Cleanup phase is beginning.
Task failed: Extract Customers
Information: 0x4001100C at Extract Customers: Aborting the current distributed transaction.
Information: 0x4001100C at Extract Internet Sales Data: Aborting the current distributed transaction.
Task failed: Stage Internet Sales
Warning: 0x80019002 at Stage Data: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (2) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
SSIS package "D:\Demofiles\Lab01\Starter\AdventureWorksETL\Stage Data.dtsx" finished: Failure.
The program '[6628] DtsDebugHost.exe: DTS' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

The first line with Error in it specifies

> An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E37  Description: "Invalid object name 'cdc.lsn_time_mapping'.".

Comment: Do you have change data captured enabled on this machine? That's what the `cdc` schema is attached to

Comment: I just tried EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_db, we just started our course on SSIS yesterday, these labfiles/demofiles were supposed to be a "tour" on how SSIS works and to learn by doing/watching, I don't think these errors were supposed to happen since the other modules work flawlessly, all except this one. I apologise if I appear like a itard but we began our course yesterday and all this is totally new to me. Would appreciate if anyone had the time to make a "howto" for newbies on how to solve this issue if possible. 

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

Your SSIS package errors, because the table `cdc.lsn_time_mapping` doesn't exist in target of your OLE DB connection. Did you specify the correct target database ?

Comment: Yes the right database is specified, it alrdy exists and is empty.

Comment: Have a look at this blog: http://www.mattmasson.com/2011/12/cdc-in-ssis-for-sql-server-2012-2/